# Formulario no muestra todos los elementos de la misma manera

Tags: php, css

En este formulario e introducido varios label junto con los inputs, el estilo de los formularios esta dado por el archivo css, nose porque en algunos label no esta en orden como en el de unidad de almacenaje y el de saldo después de ingreso y los demas si estan todos bien , en el código css e intentado alienarlo a la derecha o izquierda pero no tiene ningun cambio y siempre presenta el mismo error.
Aparte de este formulario el error aparece en otro, pero como les comento solo es en algunos label, asi como el ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.dark-matter {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 700px;
    background:  #2173a1;
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
       font-size: 13px;
   
    color:  #FFFFFF;
   
    border: none;
   
   
}

.dark-matter h1 {
      font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
       font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 40px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    margin: -10px -30px 30px -30px;
}

.dark-matter h1>span {
    display: block;
          font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
       font-size: 12px;
}

.dark-matter label {
    display:  block;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
          font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
       font-size: 15px;
}

.dark-matter label>span {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20;
    margin-top: 10px;
   
    
}

.dark-matter input[type="text"], .dark-matter input[type="number"], .dark-matter input[type="email"], .dark-matter input[type="password"], .dark-matter textarea, .dark-matter select {
    border: none;
    color: #525252;
    height: 15px;
    line-height:15px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 10px 0px 5px 5px;
    width: 70%;
  
    background: #DFDFDF;
}

.dark-matter div {
    
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    width: 70%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
   
}

.dark-matter select {
  
    appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none; 
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
    width: 70%;
    height: 35px;
    color: #525252;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.dark-matter textarea{
    height:100px;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    width: 70%;
}
.dark-matter .button {
    background: #FFCC02;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    color: #585858;
   
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFE477;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #3D3D3D;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #3D3D3D;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #3D3D3D;
    
}

.dark-matter .button:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="id" maxlength="8" id="id"  hidden required>
<h3>AUMENTAR STOCK</h3>

<form id="myform" action="" class="dark-matter" >
    
    <h1>
        <span class="validateTips">* Todos los campos son requeridos</span>
    </h1>
    <label>
        <span>*Código:</span>
        <input type="text" name="codigo" maxlength="8" id="codigo" placeholder="Escriba aquí" value="<?php echo $codigo?>"  required>      
    </label>                       
    <label>
        <span>*Material:</span>
        <input type="text" name="nombre_material" id="nombre_material" value="<?php echo $nombre_material?>" readonly="" required >          
    </label> 
    <label>
        <span>*Cantidad Stock:</span>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad_stock"  id="cantidad_stock" value="<?php echo $stock?>" readonly required >                          
    </label>                         
    <label>
        <span>*Unidad de Almacenaje:</span>
        <input type="text" name="um"  id="um" value="<?php echo $unidad?>" readonly required >    
    </label>       
    <label>
        <span>*Precio:</span>
        <input type="text" name="precio"  id="precio" value="<?php echo $precio?>"  >                                
    </label>      
    <label>
        <span>*Fecha:</span>
        <input type="text" name="fecha"  id="fecha" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i'); ?>" readonly required >                                
        <input hidden type="text" name="fecha2"  id="fecha2" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>" readonly required >                                
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>*No. Factura:</span>
        <input type="text" name="numero_factura" maxlength="10"  placeholder="Escriba aquí" id="numero_factura"  required>      
    </label>            
    <label>
        <span>* Cantidad a Ingresar:</span>
        <input type="number" name="cantidad_ingresar"  id="cantidad_ingresar" placeholder="Escriba aquí" min="1" max="9999" onchange="calcular(this.value)" required >                                
    </label>            
    <label>
        <span>*Saldo después de Ingreso:</span>
        <input type="text" name="saldo"  id="saldo" placeholder="Cantidad total" readonly required >                                
    </label>     
    <label>
        <span>*No. Factura:</span>
        <input type="text" name="numero_factura" maxlength="10"  placeholder="Escriba aquí" id="numero_factura"  required>      
    </label>     
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Ingresar" onclick="editar_material()">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Limpiar" onclick="limpiar()">                    
    
</form>
```

Comment: Parece que el codigo esta incompleto o con errores, por favor revisa que este todo el html y el css

Comment: Tienes `<input>` sin cierre explícito (`<input />`) y otros errores tipográficos. Revísalos :)

Comment: ya actualize el codigo. @Alfabravo ya probe con cierre explicito, sin cierre, si eres tan amable de decirme que errores tipograficos_

Comment: Sería buena idea que intentes no usar la propiedad float ya que a veces hace cosas raras.

Comment: No será que estas introduciendo muchos caracteres para tan pequeño espacio?

Comment: Puedes intentar o reducir la cantidad de caracteres, o reducir el largo de tu input

Comment: que me recomiendas usar en ves de float? @Mateo

Comment: ya intente reducir el numero de caracteres y siempre aparece a un lado, lo raro es que si pongo el mismo label abajo si aparece en orden, asi como el ultimo de No factura (ese solo es pruab) y tambien ya intente cambiar lo largo de los input y nada

Comment: @Luis Oliva flexbox es bastante útil.

Comment: @Alfabravo, en HTML5 ya no es necesario (ni conveniente) usar el [cierre explícito](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#tags), aunque la mayoría de navegadores aún respeta ese formato.

Answer (score 6):

El problema es que estás flotando los `span` y, cuando queda en dos líneas, el siguiente elemento será empujado a la derecha porque el primero ya está ocupando el espacio, tratando de mostrar el comportamiento:

```
--------------------     --------------------------------
| Elemento flotado |     | Campo de texto               |
| En dos líneas    |     --------------------------------
--------------------  ---------------------
                      | Otro flotado      |
                      ---------------------
```

Una posible solución es cambiar el `float: left;` por `display: inline-block;` y jugar un poco con `vertical-align`, `margin` y `padding` para mejorar la visualización.

De esta forma, no importa si son dos o más líneas, va a empujar los siguientes elementos abajo y no a la derecha:

```
--------------------     --------------------------------
| Bloque en línea  |     | Campo de texto               |
| En dos líneas    |     --------------------------------
--------------------
---------------------
| Otro bloque       |
---------------------
```

```css
.dark-matter {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 700px;
    background:  #2173a1;
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
       font-size: 13px;
   
    color:  #FFFFFF;
   
    border: none;
   
   
}

.dark-matter h1 {
      font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
       font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 40px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    margin: -10px -30px 30px -30px;
}

.dark-matter h1>span {
    display: block;
          font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
       font-size: 12px;
}

.dark-matter label {
    display:  block;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
          font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
       font-size: 15px;
}

.dark-matter label>span {
    /* Mostrar como bloque en línea y ajustar alineación vertical */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.dark-matter input[type="text"], .dark-matter input[type="number"], .dark-matter input[type="email"], .dark-matter input[type="password"], .dark-matter textarea, .dark-matter select {
    /* Ajustar alineación vertical */
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;
    color: #525252;
    height: 15px;
    line-height:15px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 10px 0px 5px 5px;
    width: 70%;
  
    background: #DFDFDF;
}

.dark-matter div {
    
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    width: 70%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
   
}

.dark-matter select {
  
    appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none; 
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
    width: 70%;
    height: 35px;
    color: #525252;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.dark-matter textarea{
    height:100px;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    width: 70%;
}
.dark-matter .button {
    background: #FFCC02;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    color: #585858;
   
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFE477;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #3D3D3D;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #3D3D3D;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #3D3D3D;
    
}

.dark-matter .button:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="id" maxlength="8" id="id"  hidden required>
<h3>AUMENTAR STOCK</h3>

<form id="myform" action="" class="dark-matter" >
    
    <h1>
        <span class="validateTips">* Todos los campos son requeridos</span>
    </h1>
    <label>
        <span>*Código:</span>
        <input type="text" name="codigo" maxlength="8" id="codigo" placeholder="Escriba aquí" value="<?php echo $codigo?>"  required>      
    </label>                       
    <label>
        <span>*Material:</span>
        <input type="text" name="nombre_material" id="nombre_material" value="<?php echo $nombre_material?>" readonly="" required >          
    </label> 
    <label>
        <span>*Cantidad Stock:</span>
        <input type="text" name="cantidad_stock"  id="cantidad_stock" value="<?php echo $stock?>" readonly required >                          
    </label>                         
    <label>
        <span>*Unidad de Almacenaje:</span>
        <input type="text" name="um"  id="um" value="<?php echo $unidad?>" readonly required >    
    </label>       
    <label>
        <span>*Precio:</span>
        <input type="text" name="precio"  id="precio" value="<?php echo $precio?>"  >                                
    </label>      
    <label>
        <span>*Fecha:</span>
        <input type="text" name="fecha"  id="fecha" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i'); ?>" readonly required >                                
        <input hidden type="text" name="fecha2"  id="fecha2" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>" readonly required >                                
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>*No. Factura:</span>
        <input type="text" name="numero_factura" maxlength="10"  placeholder="Escriba aquí" id="numero_factura"  required>      
    </label>            
    <label>
        <span>* Cantidad a Ingresar:</span>
        <input type="number" name="cantidad_ingresar"  id="cantidad_ingresar" placeholder="Escriba aquí" min="1" max="9999" onchange="calcular(this.value)" required >                                
    </label>            
    <label>
        <span>*Saldo después de Ingreso:</span>
        <input type="text" name="saldo"  id="saldo" placeholder="Cantidad total" readonly required >                                
    </label>     
    <label>
        <span>*No. Factura:</span>
        <input type="text" name="numero_factura" maxlength="10"  placeholder="Escriba aquí" id="numero_factura"  required>      
    </label>     
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Ingresar" onclick="editar_material()">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Limpiar" onclick="limpiar()">                    
    
</form>
```

Comment: muchas gracias bro, me sirvio mucho, te agradezco